# express css shows only on index pages

Tags: css, node.js, express

For some reason my web app only loads css on index files, even body and html elements that are static are only styled on index.handlebars pages. I`ve tried to change css location, href link etc, but nothing worked. 
So my app.js file looks something like this

```
const express = require('express');
//Other Consts
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
// Load Routes
const tasks = require('./routes/tasks');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const points = require('./routes/points')


// Public folder path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
});
//About Route
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about')
});

// Use routes
app.use('/tasks', tasks);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/points', points);

const port = 4000;
app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log(`Server started on ${port}`);
});
```

File tree:

```
-public
  -css
     -main.css
  -img
-views
  -layouts
    -main.handlebars <- css shows
  -users
    -login.handlebars <- css doesnt shows
    -register.handlebars <- css doesnt show
  -tasks
    -index.handlebars <- css shows
    -add.handlebars <- css doesnt show
    -edit.handlebars <- css doesnt show
  -users
    -index.handlebars <- css shows
    -add.handlebars <- css doesnt show
    -edit.handlebars <- css doesnt show
-routes
  -tasks.js
  -routes.js
  -users.js
-app.js
```

And the head link is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a subpath such as /users then it will try to find the css in /users/css/main.css

Add a '/' in front of your CSS path to always refer to your stylesheet from the base path.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">`

Comment: I`ll go and hang myself... 
Anyways, thank you, that fixed the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Try `@import url("File Address");` in header tag too